# IBM Mobile First - Scope-Elements Mapping When Register An App

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using `Mobile First 8.0` for my app development, for that I did register my app using the command of, `mfpdev app register`

However, after my registration I notice that there are some `Scope-Elements Mapping` is not added.

What should I add towards my app configuration to add `Scope-Elements Mapping` when I register the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to find and alternative that instead of registering the app, i did a automated cloning

The link bellow teaches how to fully clone using cloneApp.js,

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/01/09/cloning-application-configuration/

my steps are,

```
mfpdev app pull
node cloneApp.js myserver mfp my.app.id ios 1.0.0 1.0.1
mfpdev app push
```

Answer (score 0):

Security Scope Elements Mappings is required only if your application is trying to access an adapter endpoint protected with OAuth Scope.

Learn more about on Scope Elements Mapping in MobileFirst 8.0 Server [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/#scope-mapping).

Comment: Hi Vittal Pai,
For currently, each new version of the app we are manually registering the app at the mfpconsole site, once register we will then manually add some of our Custom Scopes.

I'm trying to change this process using mfpdev command line

Comment: There is no direct command to achieve this using MFPDev CLI. However you can pull config file and do the changes and push it back.

Comment: Previous there was an answer that posted this link,
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_scope_elements_mapping.html
, however currently im struggle to create a local copy of the application-descriptor JSON file.

Comment: Hi Vittal Pai, i tried mfpdev app pull, unzip the zip file, added scopeElementMapping and mfpdev app push. Doesn't seems to be working